# Bookmarklet: go to page & fill in form

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to make a bookmarklet to [a site where you can watch videos with any subtitle .srt file](https://tubecc.herokuapp.com/). The intent is that I can directly click it from a YouTube (or DailyMotion, or ...) video page, and instantly be transported to https://tubecc.herokuapp.com/, with the desired video url *already filled in*.

My current attempt is:

```
javascript:{vidurl=document.location.href;document.location.href=('https://tubecc.herokuapp.com');document.getElementById("url").value=vidurl;void(0);}
```

However, all this does is navigate to the website - it does not fill in the url in the box.

When I try to fill in the url box with some nonsense text as a separate operation - i.e. I'm already on https://tubecc.herokuapp.com/ and just run `document.getElementById("url").value="foobar"` from the console, or make a separate bookmarklet which only includes `javascript:{document.getElementById("url").value="foobar";void(0);}`, it *does* work - 'foobar' appears in the text box, as expected.

It only seems to fail when combined with a larger bookmarklet which navigates to the page first. At one point I suspected it had something to do with asynchronicity so I added a delay for the fill in (`javascript:{vidurl=document.location.href;document.location.href('https://tubecc.herokuapp.com');setTimeout(() => {  document.getElementById("url").value="foobar"; }, 2000);void(0);}`), but that didn't seem to help either.

PS: not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292786/create-bookmarklet-to-fill-form) - the basic principle is described there, and I am applying it. My question is about why it goes wrong in this specific situation.

Comment: Hi, where are you running this javascript code exactly ? to test?

Comment: I ran it in a Chrome bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `location.href` browser navigates to the new page and unloads all the currently running JavaScript.

To achieve what you want you'll also need a browser extension [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)  (or any userscript manager like Tampermonkey) to run JavaScript code automatically on `tubecc.herokuapp.com`.

Use this bookmarklet to navigate to `tubecc.herokuapp.com`:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  document.location.href = `https://tubecc.herokuapp.com?url=${document.location.href}`;
})();
```

Use this code in the browser extension:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const url = params.get('url');

url && (document.getElementById('url').value = url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at this line again:

```
javascript:{vidurl=document.location.href;document.location.href=('https://tubecc.herokuapp.com');document.getElementById("url").value=vidurl;void(0);}
```

When we run this on a webpage, `document.location.href=('https://tubecc.herokuapp.com')` changes the location. And so when 'https://tubecc.herokuapp.com' is loaded, there is no javascript code running.

To achieve the functionality you are looking for, you may use localstorage to store the video URL in the browser. Then redirect to your page.

Finally, you need to add a start-up script in your 'https://tubecc.herokuapp.com' webpage.

Bookmarklet:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('videoURL')=document.location.href;
document.location.href('https://tubecc.herokuapp.com')
```

Start up script within 'https://tubecc.herokuapp.com':

```
let url = window.localStorage.getItem('videoURL');
document.getElementById("url").value=url;
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify - the https://tubecc.herokuapp.com webpage does not belong to me. It's just a resource that I'm using. The only thing in this story that I am creating myself is the bookmarklet.